# Rails - How to invoke methods upon submission of form_tag?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

I have a Rails Controller, with methods for `new` and `create`. This is where I have my main form, and I know how these actions work.

I also created another view with a smaller one field form. I would like to perform an action if a user clicks submit on this form.

I created a route with get and post actions

```
match "/redemption", to: "accounts#redemption", via: [:get, :post]
```

In my `accounts#new` action, users can purchase an account. They are given a redemption code.

I decided to make a new view, where if they already have a code, they can enter it.

The logic will be fairly easy for me, but I need to know how I can perform an action on this.

Here is the form, I want to perform an action on

```
<%= form_tag('/redemption') %>

  <%= label_tag 'Enter your Redemption Code' %>
  <%= text_field_tag 'Redemption Code' %>

<%= submit_tag("Redeem") %>
```

I'm not sure how I can do this, since it doesn't involve the new and create actions. They are reserved for a different purpose.

Comment: Your question isn't clear. You want to know what should go in the `redemption` action of your controller? Because right now that form should work and call `def redemption` in your `accounts` controller.

Comment: No, I want to know how to do something if the form is submitted. Are there any rails_helpers for that? I can't say if `form.save` because I didn't declare an object. This isn't like new/create actions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

submit_tag calls the action specified by the form_for, if no action is specified then it will default to  the current action, which in this case is 'redemption' as Doon states below.  So using :action => 'your action' would probably be more clear.  More info [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html).

Comment: Thank you, I thought submit was only used for saving records via editing. I'll test this out.

Comment: Not true, sorry, it's whatever options you pass into `form_tag`, e.g the `:method` option of `form_tag`

Answer (score 1):

You need to have your form declare a block and place your submit tag inside it.   This will make it so the button posts to your redemption action.   Then you would just access the params hash like normal.

```
<%= form_tag('/redemption') do  %>

  <%= label_tag 'Enter your Redemption Code' %>
  <%= text_field_tag :redemption, 'Redemption Code' %>
  <%= submit_tag("Redeem") %>
<% end %>
```

and then in your AccountsController

```
def redemption
  call_redeem_action params[:redemption] 
end
```

you can also name your route if you want..

```
match "/redemption", to: "accounts#redemption", via: [:get, :post], as: :redemption
```

and then your form would be

```
<%= form_tag redemption_path do  %>
```

which I find easier, since if you ever need to rename that the uri, you can just adjust it in once place.